# Found nil-optional value with NSBundle Audioplayer

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

When I am initialising a AVAudio player I am getting a found nil error.
The music file is contained within a folder called 'Sounds'.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value

```
//Code

// instance
    var player : AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer();

    // ciews


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // SET UP AUDIO PLAYER AND PLAY A SOUND


        var filePath = NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sounds/pig", ofType: "mp3")!);

        var error:NSError? = nil; // craete error pointer with ampersand &


        // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
        player =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: filePath), error: &error);
```

Any input appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem there is that it is a local file so instead of string: (used for links) you use fileURLWithPath: would work but you can do it in one step using URLForResource(_:withExtension:) instead of pathForResource:

```
let fileUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Sounds/pig", withExtension: "mp3")!

player =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileUrl, error: &error)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, the example I was working off working fine (video tutorial) so not quite sure why it crashed on me using pathForResource